# Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 and ojdbc11-21.1.0.0.jar || Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is ja │ │ ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am having a springboot application where I am trying to connect to very old Oracle version 10.2.0.4.0 datasource.

My pom.xml has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        <version>21.1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my dockerfile has the similar above settings. While deploying code on the pod level, I get an exception that:

**Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is ja │ │ ORA-01882: timezone region not found**

Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 has a Timezone 4. And my springboot application ojdbc driver is not compatible with the older oracle datasource.

I googled and found that I can use below dependency for this Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 version.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

ojdbc14 is the correct jar file to be pulled either by Maven which fails : no artifacts found.

When I tried to download ojdbc14.jar and tried manual settings in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc14.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Then I get an error while deployment at pod level which says that no suitable driver found.

Now I am stuck, on how to solve this problem.

Comment: As a start, I would look at your` target/app.jar` <-- Springboot generated app jar, and see if it contains this `ojdbc14.jar` as a start before we consider the Pod/Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the correct [central maven repository for Oracle JDBC driver.](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/)
The other repository that you are using for 10.2.0.4 is not from Oracle and is very old and not supported.

Comment: Hello Nirmala, can you be of so kind and tell me the correct JDBC driver to use for Oracle version 10.2.0.4.x ? from your link. And how to use ? dependency from maven ?

Comment: 10.2.0.4.x is very old. We don't have that on central maven. 11.2.0.4 is the one that we have. Can you use the latest 21c or 19c JDBC Jar? Refer to this link on using Maven https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html

Comment: Is there a work around ? I used the driver for 21c and 19 and got the error that Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is ja │ │ ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Comment: What is the version of the Oracle database that you are trying to connect to? Can you try with a simple Java program (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) and check?